# State object structure in react-redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm creating a simple blog using React and Redux, most for learning these two libraries. Everything is working fine, my only question is about the way the state object is structured in the application. When I go to the Redux Toolkit, I see this:

[Redux Toolkit screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzymj.png)

In the state I have **a `post` object with another `post` object inside it**. My question is: **where did I defined the state in that way (with a post object inside a post object)?** Below are the content of this application:

MainPost.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { connect, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { getPostListAction } from '../store/actions/getPostListAction'

export const MainPost = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch()
   useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getPostListAction())
   })

   return (
      <div>App</div>
   )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
      post: state.post
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MainPost)
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer'
import { devToolsEnhancer } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { api } from './middleware/api'

const store = createStore(
   rootReducer,
   compose(
      devToolsEnhancer(),
      applyMiddleware(thunk),
   )
)

export default store
```

postListReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
   post: ''
}

export default function getPostListReducer(state = initialState, action) {
   if(action.type === 'getPostList') {
      return {
         ...state,
         post: action.payload
      }
   } else {
      return state
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first `post` (after `state`) is namespace of postListReducer

Here is how you use [combineReducer](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) to create a rootReducer:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  post: postListReducer, 
  other: otherReducer
})
```

And [to select data from the store](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate), you do:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
      post: state.post.post // the first "post" (after "state") is namespace of postListReducer
   }
}
```

Or if you don't want to write `state.post.post`, you can change your postListReducer to directly hold the "post" data:

```
const initialPost = ''

export default function getPostListReducer(state = initialPost, action) {
   if(action.type === 'getPostList') {
      return action.payload
   } else {
      return state
   }
}
```